# Discord Bot - embedded fields keep recurring after first command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

[image]

Okay, so, I made a discord bot using JavaScript and Discord.js, and I created embedded fields to test it out. And, well, when I first run the command, everything goes well. When I run the command a second time, whatever got printed first gets printed again, but with the original stuff, too. So, it's like, the command outputs are recurring and accumulating after the first command.

Here's the index.js file:-

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const bot = new Discord.Client();
bot.commands = new Discord.Collection();
const fs = require('fs');

bot.on('ready',()=>{
    console.log('bot online')

    //reads commands from command file
    fs.readdir('./commands', (err, files)=>{
        if(err)                                //if error occurs when reading command file
        return;
        console.log(err);

        //hello.js = hello
        let jsFile = files.filter(f =>f.split(".").pop()=='js');

        if(jsFile.length==0)
        {
            return console.log("Could not find any commands")
        }

        jsFile.forEach(f=>{
            let props = require(`./commands/${f}`);
            bot.commands.set(props.help.name, props)
        })
    })

});

bot.on('message', (message) => {
    if(message.author.bot)
    return;
    if(message.channel.type !== 'text') //doesn't work for DMs
    return;

    let prefix = 'f.';
    // hello there['hello', 'there']
    let MessageArray = message.content.split(' ');
    let cmd = MessageArray[0].slice(prefix.length);  //removes prefix when printing(?)
    let args = MessageArray.slice(1);

    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) //if message doesn't start with prefix(f)
    return;

    let commandfile = bot.commands.get(cmd);
    if(commandfile) (commandfile.run(bot,message,args))  //connects to the command folder's files

})

bot.login("token~~blah blah")
```

Here's the command - HELP file:-

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();

exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
    embed.setColor("PURPLE");
    embed.setTitle("Features");
    embed.addFields({ name: "commands", value: "hello, sup, avatar, " }, { name: "games", value: "bruh2" }, { name: "music", value: "bruh3" });
    message.channel.send(embed);
};

exports.help = {
    name: "help",
};
```

Comment: never mind, I've fixed it

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `embed` constant remains cached when you execute the command again. Moving it in the `exports.run` function will fix the issue.

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");

exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
    embed.setColor("PURPLE");
    embed.setTitle("Features");
    embed.addFields({ name: "commands", value: "hello, sup, avatar, " }, { name: "games", value: "bruh2" }, { name: "music", value: "bruh3" });
    message.channel.send(embed);
};

exports.help = {
    name: "help",
};
```